# For loop being skipped nested within an IF statement, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that I've been working on for a while. I've almost got it to where I want it, but now I've got a for loop being skipped. I have it set up to check for a number then to go into the for loop and loop through a series of rows looking for certain info. using Breakpoints I can see that it checks the IF statement and then hits the For statement, but then it skips down to the End If and never hits what is inside the for loop. Here's the code in question, not the entire macro (if the whole thing is needed I can add it):

```
        If (BranchNumber) Like "0" Or (BranchNumber) Like "1" Or (BranchNumber) Like "2" Or (BranchNumber) Like "3" Or (BranchNumber) Like "4" Or (BranchNumber) Like "5" Then

        fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A188").End(xlUp).Row

        For f = fRow To 3 Step -1
        Range("A" & f).Select
            For CountDown = 0 To 30 Step 1
                If (Range("A" & f).Value) Like Tellers(CountDown) Then
                    TellerName(count) = Range("B" & f).Value
                    MsgBox (CountDown)
                    MsgBox (Tellers(CountDown))
                    MsgBox (count)
                    MsgBox (TellerName(count))
                    MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "0" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("C" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "1" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("D" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "2" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("E" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "3" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("F" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "4" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("G" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "5" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("H" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next f
    End If
```

It is the first For loop that is hit the `for f = fRow To 3 Step -1` then it skips to the last `End If` and continues on without executing the code within the for loop.
Any ideas what is going on?

Okay, I'm adding the rest of the macro to try and clarify some of the questions:

```
Sub GetInfo()
Dim NumberBranches
Dim Branch
Dim Tellers(30), TellerTotal(30), TellerName(30)
Dim count As Long
Dim CountDown
Dim l, f As Long
Dim lRow, fRow As Long
Dim BranchNumber As Long
Dim Branches As Long
Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim strPath() As String

NumberBranches = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "12", "13", "16", "18", "19", "20")

For Branches = 0 To 15 Step 1
    BranchNumber = InputBox("What is the branch number?", "Branch Number", NumberBranches(Branches))

    Branch = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls), *.xls")
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Branch
    strPath() = Split(path, "\")
    lngIndex = UBound(strPath)
    Branch = Mid(Mid(Branch, InStrRev(Branch, "/") + 1), InStrRev(Branch, "\") + 1)
    Windows(Branch).Activate

    lRow = Sheets(1).Range("A200").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (lRow)
    count = 0
    For l = lRow To 1 Step -1
    MsgBox (l)
    MsgBox (lRow)
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A" & l).Select
        If (BranchNumber) Like "19" Then
            If (Range("B" & l).Value) Like "TC:*" Then
                Tellers(count) = Replace(Range("B" & l).Value, "TC: ", "")
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If (Range("H" & l).Value) Like "TC:*" Then
                Tellers(count) = Replace(Range("H" & l).Value, "TC: ", "")
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
        If BranchNumber <> "19" Then
            If (Range("A" & l).Value) Like "TC:" Then
                Tellers(count) = Range("B" & l).Value
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If (Range("H" & l).Value) Like "TC:" Then
                Tellers(count) = Range("I" & l).Value
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next l

    Windows("TellerTranCounts.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets(2).Activate

    If (BranchNumber) = "0" Or (BranchNumber) = "1" Or (BranchNumber) = "2" Or (BranchNumber) = "3" Or (BranchNumber) = "4" Or (BranchNumber) = "5" Then
        fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A188").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox (fRow)
        MsgBox (f)
        For f = fRow To 3 Step -1
        MsgBox (f)
        Range("A" & f).Select
            For CountDown = 0 To 30 Step 1
                If (Range("A" & f).Value) Like Tellers(CountDown) Then
                    TellerName(count) = Range("B" & f).Value
                    MsgBox (CountDown)
                    MsgBox (Tellers(CountDown))
                    MsgBox (count)
                    MsgBox (TellerName(count))
                    MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "0" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("C" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "1" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("D" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "2" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("E" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "3" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("F" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "4" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("G" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "5" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("H" & f).Value
                        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next f
    End If
    If (BranchNumber) Like "6" Or (BranchNumber) Like "7" Or (BranchNumber) Like "8" Or (BranchNumber) Like "9" Or (BranchNumber) Like "11" Or (BranchNumber) Like "12" Then
        fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A375").End(xlUp).Row

        For f = fRow To 189 Step -1
        Range("A" & f).Select
            For CountDown = 0 To 30 Step 1
                If (Range("A" & f).Value) Like Tellers(CountDown) Then
                    TellerName(count) = Range("B" & f).Value
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "6" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("C" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "7" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("D" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "8" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("E" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "9" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("F" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "11" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("G" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "12" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("H" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next f
    End If
    If (BranchNumber) Like "13" Or (BranchNumber) Like "16" Or (BranchNumber) Like "18" Or (BranchNumber) Like "19" Or (BranchNumber) Like "20" Or (BranchNumber) Like "51" Then
        fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A562").End(xlUp).Row

        For f = fRow To 377 Step -1
        Range("A" & f).Select
            For CountDown = 0 To 30 Step 1
                If (Range("A" & f).Value) Like Tellers(CountDown) Then
                    TellerName(count) = Range("B" & f).Value
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "13" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("C" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "16" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("D" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "18" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("E" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "19" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("F" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "20" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("G" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    If (BranchNumber) Like "51" Then
                        TellerTotal(count) = Range("H" & f).Value
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next f
    End If
    Dim Counted
    Dim InputCount
    Dim BranchName As String

    If BranchNumber Like "1" Then
        BranchName = "Swinney Teller Report"
        Sheets(3).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "2" Then
        BranchName = "Decatur Teller Report"
        Sheets(4).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "3" Then
        BranchName = "Tillman Teller Report"
        Sheets(5).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "4" Then
        BranchName = "Huntington Teller Report"
        Sheets(6).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "5" Then
        BranchName = "Medical Park Teller Report"
        Sheets(7).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "6" Then
        BranchName = "West Jefferson Teller Report"
        Sheets(8).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "7" Then
        BranchName = "New Haven Teller Report"
        Sheets(9).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "8" Then
        BranchName = "Waynedale Teller Report"
        Sheets(10).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "9" Then
        BranchName = "Scottsville Teller Report"
        Sheets(11).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "11" Then
        BranchName = "Columbia City Teller Report"
        Sheets(12).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "12" Then
        BranchName = "Danville Teller Report"
        Sheets(13).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "13" Then
        BranchName = "Mattoon Teller Report"
        Sheets(14).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "16" Then
        BranchName = "Lima Teller Report"
        Sheets(15).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "18" Then
        BranchName = "Stellhorn Crossing Teller Report"
        Sheets(16).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "19" Then
        BranchName = "Wayne Haven Teller Report"
        Sheets(17).Activate
    End If
    If BranchNumber Like "20" Then
        BranchName = "Hopkinsville Teller Report"
        Sheets(18).Activate
    End If

        Range("B1").Value = BranchName
        Range("B2").Formula = "=Today()"
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm-yy;@"
        Range("A5").Value = "Totals"
        Range("B5").Value = "Name of Employee"
        Range("C5").Value = "Error"
        Range("D5").Value = "Percent"
        Counted = 6
        For InputCount = 0 To 30 Step 1
            If TellerName(InputCount) <> "" Then
                Range("A" & InputCount + 6).Value = TellerTotal(InputCount)
                Range("A" & InputCount + 6).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
                Range("B" & InputCount + 6).Value = TellerName(InputCount)
                Range("D" & InputCount + 6).Formula = "=if(A" & InputCount & "<>0,(A" & InputCount & "-C" & InputCount & ")/A" & InputCount & ",""N/A"")"
                Range("D" & InputCount + 6).NumberFormat = "0.000%"
                Counted = Counted + 1
            End If
        Next
        Range("A" & Counted).Formula = "=sum(A6:A" & Counted & ")"
        Range("B" & Counted).Value = "Total Tellers"
        Range("C" & Counted).Formula = "=sum(C6:C" & Counted & ")"
        Range("D" & Counted).Formula = "=if(A" & Counted & "<>0,(A" & Counted & "-C" & Counted & ")/A" & Counted & ",""N/A"")"
        Range("D" & Counted).NumberFormat = "0.000%"
        Columns("A:D").Select
        Selection.Columns.AutoFit
        Call Format(Counted)
        Call FormatBorder(Counted)
        Range("A1").Select
        Windows(Branch).Activate
        Windows(Branch).Close (False)
Next
```

End Sub

I know it's rather long, but this is the whole thing. I've added several message boxes for trouble shooting, they would not normally be there.

What is happening is this:
I prompt the user for a branch number, then to open the file from that branch. I have code that runs through the file and pulls info from it. (This code works fine using the for loops). The based on the info pulled and the branch number it chooses where to look for the tellers names and totals on the main workbook, then inserts all this info on a sheet determined by the branch number. Then starts over asking for the next branch number and file. It continues till all 16 branch files have been processed into the main file. I'm sure there are faster ways of doing some of this, but I've not gotten this working yet so I'm not worried about optimization right now. I just need it to work.

Comment: what is the value of `fRow`? when it enters that line?

Comment: Try replacing "Like" with "="

Comment: fRow = 1 because you only reference one cell, I believe. `fRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @JoeLaviano It's referencing the last row with value, not necessarily = 1

Comment: @joelaviano I don't know why it equals 1. I have used other statements such as this and it's never equaled 1. It should equal the value I set it to in the `fRow =` statement, in this case 188. I can't set it to the number of rows total because I only want it to search through the first 188 rows. The rest are searched later.

Comment: @gary'sStudent I tried switching to using '=', but no change it still skips over the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies with this line:

```
fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A188").End(xlUp).Row
```

While this will get the last used row in many cases, if all the data from A1 to A188 is filled with data, the calculation will return 1, as that's the top cell in the range, as it hasn't found a blank cell to end it's search on.

there are 3 possible solutions to this, depending on how your data will appear:

1. If there are always more than 188 rows of data, then set fRow equal to 188 without having to do a calculation
   `fRow = 188`
2. If there are not any gaps in the data, go from the top down,Count from the top to the bottom
   `fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xldown).Row`
   then check to see if it is more than 188
3. If there are gaps, then search from past the last possible row
   `fRow = Sheets(2).cells(sheets(2).Usedrange.Rows.Count+1,1).End(xlUp).Row`
   and check to see if it is over 188, and set to 188 otherwise

Comment: That was it. Because there are no gaps in the data in column A it was always returning 1. I set fRow to 188 and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you inspected the value of fRow. It could be that variable fRow is less than variable f when the loop starts, so the condition to start the loop is never met.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the variable fRow is assuming the row value of the first not empty cell in your column `fRow = Sheets(2).Range("A188").End(xlUp).Row`

So, fRow has a value from 1 to 188, and your loop statement `For f = fRow To 3 Step -1` will only work if fRow is greater than 3.

Please, check the value of fRow before it enters in your loop.

Also, **IF** BranchNumber can be only 1,2,3,4 or 5, you don't have to check if it's 2 when you already know it's 1....Use the Else condition:

```
If (BranchNumber) Like "1" Then
   TellerTotal(count) = Range("C" & f).Value
   MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
   count = count + 1
   ElseIf (BranchNumber) Like "2" Then
        TellerTotal(count) = Range("E" & f).Value
        MsgBox (TellerTotal(count))
         count = count + 1
   End If      
End If
```

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense to me. I have other similar statements like this one where the `For f = fRow To 3 Step -1` and fRow starts at what I set it to in the `fRow =` statement, in this case 188. Then f would count down by one's till reaching 3. (There are 0 blank cells in the range 'A188:A3')

Comment: So, if there is 0 blank cells in the range A188:A3, your fRow will be 3